# Regular expression for username start with @

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I want to capture all the username that starts with **@** symbol and also there is no character before it.

Until now I have a regular expression that could get all the usernames but it also fetches the usernames that have characters before it but i want to ignore them.

```
/@[\w\d]+/g
```

[image]

Comment: try giving a space character ` ` before `@`, see if that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a positive look behind to verify that the `@` is preceded by space or start of the string.

```
(?<= |^)@[\w\d]+
```

- `(?<= |^)` Positive look behind. Ensures that `@` is preceded by  space or `^` start of the string. Not the look aheads, doesn't consume any characters, it just checks.

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/1O1CBv/1)

**Example**

```
$string = "My name is @john_doe from test@test.com";
preg_match("/(?<= |^)@[\w\d]+/", $string, $matches);   

print_r($matches);
// Array ( 
//     [0] => @john_doe 
// )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmed I have added a small explanation. Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

The following *regex (using [non-word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html))* should do it :

```
(^|\B)@\w+
```

see [demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/kUH0lh/3)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add **^**. So the regex looks like `/^@[\w\d]+/g`

Answer (score 0):

Just need to add the term to check @ is at the begining

/^@[\w\d]+/g